# Problema ao criar minimax em jogo de xadrez

Tags: c, algoritmo, jogos, inteligência-artificial

Estou codificando um jogo de xadrez apenas no C puro. O jogo em si está pronto, estou a algum tempo tentando desenvolver o algoritmo de minimax. Atualmente o algoritmo está quase pronto, porém ainda não está retornando e eu acho que o problema está na função do minimax.

Atual código abaixo, eu tentei rodar ele, mas quando a IA tenta jogar, simplesmente o jogo termina, aparenta ser um loop novamente, mas não identifiquei ele.

```
// liberando o lixo acumulado
void LiberarMemoria(Lista_ia* root){
    Jogadas* next = root->head;
    while(next != NULL){
        Jogadas* tmp = next;
        next = next->prox;
        free(tmp);
    }
    free(root);
}

// Simulate 5 turn ahead for choose the best current move
Jogadas *minimax(int tabuleiro[TAM][TAM], int depth, int Player, Jogadas* novaJogada){

    // Copy the board for don't change it
    int i, j, copia[TAM][TAM];
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=9; j++){
            copia[i][j] = tabuleiro[i][j];
        }
    }

    copia[novaJogada->lin_dps][novaJogada->col_dps] = copia[novaJogada->lin_atual][novaJogada->col_atual];
    copia[novaJogada->lin_atual][novaJogada->col_atual] = 0;

    if(gameover(tabuleiro) == 1){
        // Se o Player 2 (Computer) jogou e ganhou, agr seria a vez do player 1
        if (Player == 1){
            novaJogada->pontuacao = -99999;
            return novaJogada;
        }
        else{
            novaJogada->pontuacao = 99999;
            return novaJogada;
        }
    }

    if(depth == 0){
        return novaJogada;
    }

    Lista_ia *Moves = inicializarLista();

    verificar_jogadas_possiveis(copia, Moves, Player);

    Jogadas *tmp;

    // Simulating the current Player 2 (Computer) move
    if(Player == 2){
        novaJogada->pontuacao = -9999;

        for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox){

            Jogadas *BestMove = minimax(copia, depth - 1, 1, tmp);

            if(BestMove->pontuacao > novaJogada->pontuacao){
                novaJogada->pontuacao = BestMove->pontuacao;
            }
        }
        LiberarMemoria(Moves);
        return novaJogada;
    }
    // Simulating the best Player 1 move
    else{
        novaJogada->pontuacao = 9999;

        for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox){

            Jogadas *BestMove = minimax(copia, depth - 1, 2, tmp);

            if(BestMove->pontuacao < novaJogada->pontuacao){
                novaJogada->pontuacao = BestMove->pontuacao;
            }
        }
        LiberarMemoria(Moves);
        return novaJogada;
    }
}

Jogadas *IniciarMinMax(int tabuleiro[TAM][TAM], int depth, int Player){
    Lista_ia *Moves = inicializarLista();

    // Copy the board for don't change it
    int i, j, copia[TAM][TAM];
    for(i=0; i<=9; i++){
        for(j=0; j<=9; j++){
            copia[i][j] = tabuleiro[i][j];
        }
    }

    verificar_jogadas_possiveis(copia, Moves, Player);

    Jogadas* bestMove = NULL;
    Jogadas* tmp;

    for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox){
        // iniciando busca
        Jogadas *current = minimax(copia, depth, Player, tmp);
        if(bestMove == NULL || current->pontuacao > bestMove->pontuacao){
            bestMove = current;
        }
    }
    // clonando resultado para retornar antes de liberar a memoria
    Jogadas *result = (Jogadas*)malloc(sizeof(Jogadas));
    result->lin_atual = bestMove->lin_atual;
    result->col_atual = bestMove->col_atual;
    result->lin_dps = bestMove->lin_dps;
    result->col_dps = bestMove->col_dps;
    result->pontuacao = bestMove->pontuacao;

    LiberarMemoria(Moves);

    return result;
}
```

Informações adicionais que pediram para me ajudarem no problema.

```
typedef struct jogadas{
    int lin_atual;
    int col_atual;
    int lin_dps;
    int col_dps;
    int pontuacao;
    struct jogadas *prox;
}Jogadas;

typedef struct turno{
    int turn;
    struct turno *prox;
}Turno;

typedef struct lista_ia{
    struct jogadas *head;
}Lista_ia;

void verificar_jogadas_possiveis(int tabuleiro[TAM][TAM], Lista_ia *Allmoves, int Player){
    int i, j, m, n;
    Jogadas *tmp;
    for(i=1; i<9; i++){
        for(j=1; j<9; j++){
            if(checar_peca_inimiga(tabuleiro[i][j]) == Player){
                for(m=1; m<9; m++){
                    for(n=1; n<9; n++){
                        tmp = (Jogadas*)malloc(sizeof(Jogadas));
                        tmp->lin_atual = i;
                        tmp->col_atual = j;
                        tmp->lin_dps = m;
                        tmp->col_dps = n;
                        if(validar_jogada(tabuleiro, tmp) == 1){
                            //tmp->pontuacao += pontuar_jogadas(tabuleiro, m, n);
                            tmp->pontuacao = 0;
                            tmp->prox = Allmoves->head;
                            Allmoves->head = tmp;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Free memory space
    free(tmp);
}
```

OBS: o for está correto, eu havia me esquecido mas o tabuleiro é uma matriz 10x10 onde as bordas servem apenas para orientar o jogador de onde jogar, como uma batalha naval... A, B, C, D... e 1, 2, 3, 4... etc.

Comment: "Ele da erro e fecha"... Qual erro?

Comment: Aparentemente ele entra em um loop, pois erro mesmo não aparece nenhum, ele só diz que o programa não está mais respondendo.

Comment: Não entrando no mérito da semântica do programa: a condição de terminação da recursão de `minimax` está retornando um ponteiro de `Jogadas` sem estar inicializado. Talvez se retornasse `NULL` fosse melhor? Só acho.

Comment: Um erro claro é o tamanho do tabuleiro `for(int i = 0; i <=9; i++)` deveria ser `i < 8`. Coloca alguns logs dentro desses loop para achar onde esta travando, olhando assim fica complicado se quer dizer o que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Poderia dizer a qual profundidade sua busca vai? Quando estava na faculdade fiz um jogo de xadrez tbm, e como quase não existia otimização no código e o algoritmo de avaliação de posição era extremamente lento, se colocasse ele pra procurar qualquer coisa mais funda do que 5, ele facilmente passava de 15 minuto buscando uma jogada.

Comment: A profundidade a principio é 5 também. Sobre o for e demais erros lógicos eu já corrigi, mas a estrutura em si do minimax está correta? Ele não funciona de jeito algum.

Comment: O que o ponteiro `prox` de `Jogadas` faz? Ele aponta a próxima jogada, ou para outras possíveis jogadas no mesmo turno? O seu `for` que chama a recursão não parece fazer sentido. O `tmp` serve para que ali? Onde é que ele faz a checagem da "pontuação" atual para comparar qual a melhor jogada? Tem muita coisa que não faz sentido ainda. Posta sua struct `Jogadas` e a função `verificar_jogadas_possiveis` para ver se ajuda a entender algumas coisas.

Comment: Adicionei as informações que pediu. O ponteiro prox aponta para a proxima jogada dentro da lista de jogadas de um mesmo player. O tmp ali serve para conseguir passar um for por todas as jogadas dentro da lista de structs Jogadas, não sei fazer de uma forma mais simples. A pontuação é feita com base em quem você mata na simulação, peão são 10 pontos, cavalo 30, etc...

Comment: da uma olhada agora se o código que arrumei da alguma ajuda.

Comment: Eu fiz todas as modificações e o codigo agr aparenta estar mais otimizado, mas ainda estou em duvida sobre onde o "Jogar" deveria ficar. Ele ainda não funciona mas acho q estamos no caminho certo, fiz alguns testes e ele retorna algumas jogadas mas coisas nada haver infelizmente, postei o atual codigo pra re-analise.

Comment: Você não deve realizar as jogadas no `tabuleiro` mas sim na `copia`. Antes de retornar a `novaJogada` você deve atribuir o valor da posição atual do tabuleiro para ela. O `free` dentro da sua função `verificar_jogadas_possiveis` hora ou outra vai causar erros inexplicáveis, por que ir liberar uma jogada valida. Agora para jogar você só precisa criar uma lista de jogadas `Lista_ia ` antes de chamar o minimax, e ir passando uma a uma para ele, e depois escolher a melhor.

Comment: Corrigi a parte de realizar a jogada simulada, e sobre o verificar_jogadas eu ja corrigi, so n editei aqui no site. Pode explicar melhor a parte final que você disse sobre fazer uma nova Lista_ia, ou dar um exemplo? Sinto que estamos perto de resolver, finalmente.

Comment: Ainda não consegui chegar a um resultado plausivel nos testes apesar de inumeras tentativas, mais alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: O que exatamente seria `Ainda não consegui chegar a um resultado plausivel`?

Comment: As jogadas escolhidas ainda não são boas... ele se mata ou joga bem mal, parece até aleatorio apesar dos meus esforços =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo você precisa implementar o analisador de posição. Ele é a real inteligência do seu jogo. Quanto melhor você fizer ele, melhor serão as decisões na hora de realizar a jogada.

```
void ValorPosicaoEstatica(int[TAM][TAM] t, Jogadas* jogada)
{
    // calcular quem esta com vantagem e de quanto e atribuir em jogada
}
```

Quanto a lista que eu tinha falado era algo assim.

```
// função auxiliar para dar o start no MinMax
Jogadas* IniciarMinMax(int tabuleiro[TAM][TAM], int profundidade, int player)
{
    Lista_ia *Moves = (Lista_ia*)malloc(sizeof(Lista_ia));
    Moves->head = NULL;

    int x[TAM][TAM];
    for(i=0; i< TAM; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < TAM; j++)
        {
            x[i][j] = tabuleiro[i][j];
        }
    }
    verificar_jogadas_possiveis(x, Moves, player);
    Jogadas* bestMove = NULL;
    for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox)
    {
        // iniciando busca
        Jogadas *current = minimax(x, profundidade, player, tmp);
        if(bestMove == NULL || current->pontuacao > bestMove->pontuacao)
        {
            bestMove = current;
        }
    }
    // clonando resultado para retornar antes de liberar a memoria
    Jogadas *result = (Jogadas*)malloc(sizeof(Jogadas));
    result->lin_atual = bestMove->lin_atual;
    result->col_atual = bestMove->col_atual;
    result->lin_dps = bestMove->lin_dps;
    result->col_dps = bestMove->col_dps;
    result->pontuacao = bestMove->pontuacao;

    LiberarMemoria(Moves);

    return result;
}
```

Adicionei uma função de limpeza, porque no xadrez a quantidade de nós que seu minimax vai correr não é pouco. Como ele não realiza a "poda", ele percorrera todos os nós. Então deve analisar no mínimo 3 ou 4 milhão de nós em uma busca de profundidade 5. Após o sexto turno isso deve ir bem além, só caindo no final de jogo.

```
// liberando o lixo acumulado
void LiberarMemoria(Lista_ia* root)
{
    Jogadas* next = root->head;
    while(next != NULL)
    {
        Jogadas* tmp = next;
        next = next->prox;
        free(tmp);
    }
    free(root);
}
```

E por fim refiz o método minmax para fazer sentido com a função de start. Acredito que deve estar ok.

```
Jogadas *minimax(int tabuleiro[TAM][TAM], int depth, int Player, Jogadas* novaJogada)
{

    // Clona o tabuleiro e executa a jogada pedida
    int copia[TAM][TAM];
    for(i=0; i< TAM; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j < TAM; j++)
        {
            copia[i][j] = tabuleiro[i][j];
        }
    }
    copia[jogada->lin_dps][jogada->col_dps] = copia[jogada->lin_atual][jogada->col_atual];
    copia[jogada->lin_atual][jogada->col_atual] = 0;

    if(gameover(copia))
    {
        // voce precisa dizer como o jogo acabou
        // se o computador ganhou novaJogada->pontuacao = 99999;
        // se o jogador ganhou novaJogada->pontuacao = -99999;
        // se empatou novaJogada->pontuacao = 0;
        return novaJogada;
    }


    // se a busca ja terminou só retorna o valor da jogada
    if(depth == 0)
    {
        // aqui voce precisa criar a função para o programa saber que valor dar 
        // a posição atual, de quem esta na vantagem e por quanto;
        ValorPosicaoEstatica(copia, novaJogada);
        return novaJogada;
    }

    Lista_ia *Moves = (Lista_ia*)malloc(sizeof(Lista_ia));
    Moves->head = NULL;

    verificar_jogadas_possiveis(copia, Moves, Player);

    Jogadas *tmp;

    if(Player == 2)
    {
        novaJogada->pontuacao = -9999;
        for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox)
        {
            Jogadas *BestMove = minimax(copia, depth - 1, 1, tmp);
            if(BestMove->pontuacao > novaJogada->pontuacao)
            {
                novaJogada->pontuacao = BestMove->pontuacao;
            }
        }
        LiberarMemoria(Moves);
        return novaJogada;
    }
    else
    {
        novaJogada->pontuacao = 9999;
        for(tmp = Moves->head; tmp != NULL; tmp = tmp->prox)
        {
            Jogadas *BestMove = minimax(copia, depth - 1, 2, tmp);
            if(BestMove->pontuacao < novaJogada->pontuacao)
            {
                novaJogada->pontuacao = BestMove->pontuacao;
            }
        }
        LiberarMemoria(Moves);
        return novaJogada;
    }
}
```

Comment: Já corrigi os erros apontados, mas ainda há algo atrapalhando seu funcionamento. As jogadas_possiveis retorna uma lista de struct Jogadas com todas as jogadas possiveis com aquele tabuleiro, de um player. O algoritmo como um todo, olhando o psudocódigo que encontro na wikipedia, não consigo ver diferença, só a adaptação pro jogo. Esse algoritmo é meio complicado de se utilizar, pelo menos eu estou sentido essa dificuldade. Se estiver disponível para conversarmos mais sobre o assunto me mande uma msg.

Comment: Eu fiz algumas alterações, no fim me sobrou uma duvida, como eu devo chamar então a função? Só jogar = IniciarMinimax(parametros)?

Comment: Exatamente, quanto as jogadas serem ruins/suicidas, ai depende do seu analisador de posição. Ele é quem vai dizer pro seu minimax qual é a melhor jogada.

Comment: Eu não tenho esse analisador de posição, eu calculo só o valor de cada peça e se matar ela ganha essa pontuação, foi só até ai que consegui pensar, mas ainda assim não roda, tem algo de errado no minimax eu acho. Se puder me add no discord ou skype pra eu poder tirar mais algumas duvidas, até lhe mostro o programa inteiro, talvez ajude a entender se há algum erro.

Comment: Para vc testar, da para usar esse sistema de de somente contar os pontos de cada jogador. Peças Branco - Peças Preto = Quem esta na vantagem. Isso seria apenas para testar. As jogadas começariam a fazer algum sentido. Mas ainda estariam bem ruins. Porque o valor de cada peça varia dependendo da situação/posição, e se você simplesmente der um valor fixo a ele, ele quase sempre vai ignorar jogadas boas, pela vantagem material.

Comment: Que outras coisas eu poderia analisar além da peça eliminada? Eu precisaria dizer jogadas "prontas" ou ja conhecidas e ver se ele a reconhece em um dos padrões do minimax, por exemplo? O codigo ainda não funciona, mas esse final de semana vou me dedicar inteiramente a faze-lo rodar. Deve ser alguma besteira que ta deixando um loop.

Comment: A posição de cada peça, por exemplo, um cavalo em A3 em quase todas as ocasiões é pior que em C3. Então o cavalo em A3 valeria -0.01; O par de bispo tende a ser mais forte que um par de cavalos. Então par de bispo +0.1; Realizar o roque em muitas vezes é melhor do que deixar o rei parado no meio do tabuleiro. Rei protegido no canto +0.1; Você precisa olhar para o tabuleiro e pensar: "Quem esta ganhando? O que me levou a chegar a essa conclusão?" Depois implementar isso ao seu xadrez. Muitas vezes a soma das peças é igual, mas é fácil identificar que esta na vantagem.

Comment: Entendi, ainda nem consegui fazer o codigo rodar, descobri que o minimax fica em um loop pq quando chega na profundidade 0 ele não encerra a função, não sei porque, estou tentando entender pq se há o return novaJogada no if depth == 0.